# How to position a button inside a list element?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, html-lists

I have a short Ordered List that contains 2 items.  Within the second Item, I want to position a button on the right.  The CSS is giving me trouble so I am posting it here with the hope that someone more skilled can help.

Here's the markup:

```
<ol>
    <li>Go here to  <a href="review.aspx">perform an internal review</a>.</li>
    <li>When satisfied with the internal review, click the button on the right and then go to the Staging environment for a final review.<span style="width: 25%; display: block;float: right;" ><asp:Button runat="server" runat="server" ID="StageChanges" Text="Stage Changes" OnClick="StageChanges"/></span></li>
</ol>
```

Ideally I want the button to be inline with list element 2.  The text for list element 2 should wrap appropriately.  Right now the button goes below the second list element.

I tried a couple of variations, but nothing seems to work as I'd like.  One variation included specifying the width of the second list element, but this removed the number 2 from being displayed (or moved it over to be in front of the button).

Thank you in advance!

Edited to add image:
[image]

Comment: I just tried the code the markup that you posted here and is not behaving like you said you can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/bZkm5/

Comment: @GabrielMonteiroNepomuceno I don't see the button at all in your link.

Comment: one has to remove the <asp:-portion so that one can see the button ;)

Comment: Can you send the rendered html (use the view-source in your browser so we can see the generated html code)

Comment: I added an image to show what's going on for me.  Is this how you see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I crop your code down a bit it works splendidly. The button is being positioned inline of the second list element:

```
<li>
    When satisfied with the internal review, click the button on the right and then go to the Staging environment for a final review.
    <button>Stage Changes</button>
</li>
```

Keep in mind that button is one of those few form elements that gets its text from the content it wraps, not from a text-attribute.

Comment: I added an image to show what's going on for me.  Is this how you see it?

Comment: Ok, How can I get it so the 2nd list element is essentially 2 columns, with the button being the only thing in the 2nd column.

Comment: @Mark This is the answer to your question "Ideally I want the button to be inline with list element 2."  If you have additional questions, you should ask them separately.

Comment: You are correct. I'll try again later with better wording for my question.

Answer (score 1):

Add CSS for list items

```
ol li{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding that as an inline style, but it didn't change anything.  I added an image to show what's going on.